# PHPMailer is not sending mail

Tags: php

Tring to send a confirmation mail after from saving data in the database. I have used PHPMailer.

My Code

```
<?php include_once 'config/init.php'; ?>
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

$user = new user();

if(isset($_POST['submitsignup'])){

$date = array();

if($_POST['email']=='' || $_POST['password']=='' || $_POST['first_name']=='' || $_POST['last_name']==''){
    echo "Fill all the stuff";
}
else{ 
    $result=$user->checkemails($_POST['email']);
        if(!$result){
            $data["email"] = $_POST['email'];
            $data['password'] = $_POST['password'];
            $data['first_name'] =$_POST['first_name'];
            $data['last_name'] = $_POST['last_name'];

            $token = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm!$#()/1234567890';
            $token = str_shuffle($token);
            $token = substr($token,0,10);

            $user->signup($data,$token);

            include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->setFrom("ahsan44411@gmail.com");
            $mail->addAddress($data["email"],$data["first_name"]);
            $mail->Subject = "Please verify name";
            $mail->isHTML(true);
            $mail->Body = "Please click on the Link below <br><br> 
            <a href='localhost/index.php'></a>";
            if($mail->send()){
                echo "Message sent";
            }else{
                echo "Something went wrong";
            }
        }
    else{
            echo "Email aleay present";
        }
    }   

}


$template = new Template('templates/signuptemp.php');
```

But I am getting errors like this

**Warning: require_once(lib/PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp64\www\jobLister\config\init.php on line 10**

**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'lib/PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp64\www\jobLister\config\init.php on line 10**

My config\init.php

```
<?php 


require_once 'config.php';

//Autoloader
function __autoload($class_name){
    require_once 'lib/'.$class_name.'.php';
}
?>
```

I can't really understand the problem, I would appreciate if you could explain the reason why this is happening.Cheers

**Edit: Its not working because I am already using an autoloader to load my files and I should not be using include_once function in this case**

Comment: Why are you writing you own autoloader? Basically it needs to be smarter and split the fully qualified classname to correspond to directories. But really, why not just use composer?

Comment: I am using an autoloader so I dont have to use require_once for every file I have in lib.

Comment: Did you get it. The question? What was the problem

Comment: You can `echo $class_name;` before `require_once` to get the class name which it could not find in a file.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont know how that would help me

Comment: The error message says the fundamental reason, why it crashes. You don't have such a file required by your autoloader. Also, why are you using include_once inside your code to attach class file if you have already an autoloader defined?

Comment: Thanks, I figured that out after I posted this question.But it still gives me one more error. It seems that it can not find the PHPMailer.php file even when it is loaded

Comment: That's not enough information on how you set it up now on your environment. Install it afresh using the current installation and usage docs: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/UPGRADING.md. It's evident that your simple autoloading stub fails (it's not cross-platform anyway).

Comment: The error message clearly says that it cannot find the file on path "lib/PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception.php". Where is your init.php file? Is it inside the "config" folder? And is there "libs" folder inside "config"? Your "libs" folder may be outside "config" folder. So, in your init.php use `require_once '../lib/'.$class_name.'.php'` or something. What I mean to say is, check if the paths are correct or not.

Comment: Put the statement: include_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php"; on the top of the page .

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Composer. But if you are not familiar with it, then just download the [zip](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/archive/master.zip) file and extract it in your website's directory. Create some test file like `test.php` or something and try this code.

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require '<use correct path to PHPMailer here>/src/Exception.php';
require '<use correct path to PHPMailer here>/src/PHPMailer.php';

$body = "Hi! It works!";

$fromEmail = "<from address>"; //fill this
$password="<your secret password to gmail>"; //fill this
$toEmail = "<to address>"; //fill this

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->isSMTP();    
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;           
    $mail->Username = $fromEmail;        
    $mail->Password = $password;                
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                      
    $mail->Port = 587;                           
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, 'EMAIL FROM PHP TEST CODE');
    $mail->addAddress($toEmail);  

    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                         
    $mail->Subject = 'TEST EMAIL';
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AltBody = 'IT WORKS!!!';
    $mail->send();
    echo 'mail sent!';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
```

Make sure you made the necessary setting in your gmail account to allow PHP to send mails. Without that, it won't work. If this code works, then build your program on top of this.